# location based inline popup jquery geoio

Tags: jquery, geolocation, geoip, jquery-cookie

im trying to add a location based popup to a popup i already have but i dont want both of them to show ie. if there is the USA or Canada i want them to see one popup and if there in the rest of the world see the other.

So far with the help of JFK from the forum ive a link to the jquery cookie api plus this :

```
    function openFancybox() {
setTimeout( function() {$('#various3').trigger('click'); },5000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
var visited = $.cookie('visited');
if (visited == 'yes') {
    return false;
} else {
    openFancybox();
}
$.cookie('visited', 'yes', { expires: 0 });
$('#various3').fancybox();
});
```

I would like to use the [netimpact](http://www.netimpact.com) api to determine where the user is coming from unless if theres a better/easyier way to do it.

In the netimpact api they give a list of api options (im going with ip address to location) but after that you need to chose between : JSON, pipe (|), semi-colon(;), comma(,), tab (/t).  im not sure which one i need and from here i dont realy have a clue where to go and how to intergrate it with the above script (as you can probaly guess ive not realy done this befor)

any helps much appreciated

regards

sam